# TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not int

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit

On a raspberry, i get this message using Adafruit CharLCD:
I don't understand why it talks about an argument that must be string..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lcd.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "./lcd.py", line 39, in main
    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 143, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py", line 278, in setup
TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not int
```

Here is my code:

```
#LCD variables
lcd_rs= 18
lcd_en= 23
lcd_d4= 12
lcd_d5= 16
lcd_d6= 20
lcd_d7= 21
lcd_backlight= 4
lcd_columns= 16
lcd_rows= 2


lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

lcd.message('Humidite %s' %(humidity))
```

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be string, not int

Comment: It is a very clear error message. You don't have any idea what it is complaining about?

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/blob/master/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py#L143

if you add a print statement here you can find out

Answer (score -2):

solved my problem:
Missing Adafruit_python_GPIO.
Installed it and everything is fine now!
Thank you all